# Placement of Frame is unexpected

Tags: python, tkinter

*This is what I want to achieve:*

[image: This What I wanna achieve]

---

*What I have done so far*

[image: What I have done so far]

---

Problem:

- Placement of widgets

---

I am just experimenting with placement using pack creating this simple Gui but the placement is being problem for me, just posting code below.

```
from ctypes import windll
from tkinter import Tk, ttk

import tkextrafont


class aboutUs(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.background_color = "#514C4C"
        self.title("About Us")
        self.geometry("500x500")
        self.aboutUs = 'About us'
        self.configure(background=self.background_color)
        self.resizable(False, False)

        # UI Styles and variables
        self.background_color = "#514C4C"
        self.background_color2 = "#D9D9D9"

        self.style = ttk.Style()

        # resources
        self.frameFonts1 = tkextrafont.Font(file="resources/Roboto_Mono/static/RobotoMono-Regular.ttf")

        # calling the components
        self.uppFrame()
        self.middleFrame()

    def uppFrame(self):
        aboutFrame = ttk.Frame(self,
                               style="TFrame",
                               height=111,
                               width=500)
        self.style.configure("TFrame", background=self.background_color)

        aboutFrame.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        ttk.Label(aboutFrame,
                  text="About Us",
                  font=('Roboto Mono', 40),
                  background=self.background_color,
                  foreground="white").place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")

    def middleFrame(self):
        sepFrame = ttk.Frame(self, style="TFrame")
        self.style.configure("TFrame", background=self.background_color2, height=60, width=500)
        sepFrame.pack(side="bottom", fill="both")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)  # This line is important as it allows not to make fonts blurry
    aboutUsWindow = aboutUs()
    aboutUsWindow.mainloop()
```

*I hope you can help me!*

Comment: You used same style name *"TFrame"* for both the upper and bottom frames.  Use separate names instead.  And you need to specify `height` option in `ttk.Frame(...)` for the bottom frame like that for the upper frame.  Also don't set the background color of the root window to the same background color of the upper frame, otherwise you will not get the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistakes, I make the changes right away but about the label you are pointing I did that because the label had background color, I could share img link how it looked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistakes:

- same style name `"TFrame"` for both the upper and bottom frames
- specify the height and width in frame and not in the style

  ```
  from ctypes import windll
   from tkinter import Tk, ttk

   import tkextrafont


   class aboutUs(Tk):
       def __init__(self):
           super().__init__()

           self.background_color = "#514C4C"
           self.title("About Us")
           self.geometry("500x500")
           self.aboutUs = 'About us'
           self.configure(background=self.background_color)
           self.resizable(False, False)

           # UI Styles and variables
           self.background_color = "#514C4C"
           self.background_color2 = "#D9D9D9"

           self.style = ttk.Style()

           # resources
           self.frameFonts1 = tkextrafont.Font(file="resources/Roboto_Mono/static/RobotoMono-Regular.ttf")

           # calling the components
           self.uppFrame()
           self.middleFrame()

       def uppFrame(self):
           aboutFrame = ttk.Frame(self,
                                  style="TFrame",
                                  height=111,
                                  width=500)
           self.style.configure("uppFrame.TFrame", background=self.background_color)

           aboutFrame.pack(side="top", fill="both")
           ttk.Label(aboutFrame,
                     text="About Us",
                     font=('Roboto Mono', 40),
                     background=self.background_color,
                     foreground="white").place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")

       def middleFrame(self):
           sepFrame = ttk.Frame(self, style="TFrame", height=60, width=500)
           self.style.configure("midFrame.TFrame", background=self.background_color2)
           sepFrame.pack(side="bottom", fill="both")


   if __name__ == '__main__':
       windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)  # This line is important as it allows not to make fonts blurry
       aboutUsWindow = aboutUs()
       aboutUsWindow.mainloop()
  ```